# Magento2 - SOAP API not authorized issue

Tags: api, magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I tried to call SOAP API of Magento 2 but I could not call successfully.

### Here is my source code:

```
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/Zend/Server/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/Zend/Soap/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/Zend/Soap/Client/Common.php');

$token = "olourdje47c5c5g66md4gfceyslo9y1p";
$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$wsdlUrl = "http://mage2.dev/soap?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1";
$serviceArgs = array("customerId" => 1);

$soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetById($serviceArgs);
var_dump($soapResponse);
```

---

### The error message shown on browser is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Sender] Consumer is
> not authorized to access %resources in
> /vagrant/data/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/Zend/Soap/Client.php:1118
> Stack trace: #0
> /vagrant/data/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/Zend/Soap/Client.php(1118):
> SoapClient->__soapCall('customerCustome...', Array, NULL, NULL, Array)
>
> ## 1 /vagrant/data/magento2/test_api.php(28): Zend\Soap\Client->__call('customerCustome...', Array) #2
>
> /vagrant/data/magento2/test_api.php(28):
> Zend\Soap\Client->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetById(Array) #3 {main}
> thrown in
> /vagrant/data/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/Zend/Soap/Client.php
> on line 1118

---

The token in the source code was the access token of the integration with all resource I created on Magento back-end. The integration was active.

I could call the SOAP API without resource need successfully. For example, the Get function in the catalogProductRepositoryV1 service.

I wonder if there are any missing procedures I have to complete first for using SOAP API with resource need.

I will thank you so much for any helps.

Comment: have you found magento1 wsdl.xml file similarly in magento2?

Comment: @amitbera, have you found magento1 wsdl.xml file similarly in magento2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the root cause.
I did not miss any procedures for the API configuration.

The problem is I am using the VM provided by Magento for running the Magento2.
The function apache_request_headers does not work in the VM environment so that the php cannot get "Authorization" in the header of the HTTP request.

I spent a whole afternoon for debugging.

Comment: wow... I ran into the same issue a while back and gave up on it. Thanks for that info. I noticed they've since pulled that VM entirely.

Comment: I'm glad that this helped you.

Answer (score 2):

click on `System -> Integration` Menu it will show you list api users. From that edit anyone user it will show you as below screen shot from that copy `Access Token` and assign to the `$token` variable.

And run your code it should work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your case file path are wrong. Try the below code

```
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

$token = "olourdje47c5c5g66md4gfceyslo9y1p";
$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$wsdlUrl = "http://mage2.dev/soap?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1";
$serviceArgs = array("customerId" => 1);
try{  
$soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetById($serviceArgs);
var_dump($soapResponse);
}catch(Exception $e){echo 'Un-authorized Req:'.$e->getMessage();}
```

Note: $token must be the 'Access Token', shown by @magento two in the above post.